# Dynamically changing source of image - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I got the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41ghiuvjdvL._SL75_SS50_.jpg" />
</div>

<br />

<div class="photo">
    <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/27520_119569768054263_2432_q.jpg" />
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
// getting src of bottom image
var bottomSrc = $(".photo img").find("src");

// getting src of top image
var topSrc = $(".image img").find("src");

$(".photo").click(function() {
    // changing sources
    // topSrc.attr("src", bottomSrc);
    // topSrc.replaceWith(bottomSrc);
    topSrc.replace(bottomSrc);
})​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyMZd/1)

When the bottom image is clicked, I want the `src` of the top image to be replaced with the bottom image's `src`, so that both images are the same.

Why does the supplied code does not work?

Comment: you want to use `.attr('src')` to get the value of the src attribute, not `.find()` which finds child elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$(".photo").click(function() {
    var src=$(this).children("img").attr("src");
    $(".image img").attr("src",src);
})​;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/LyMZd/2/)

You need to get and set the src attribute, using attr() function in jQuery